# Boost Spirit Karma repeat same output for every entry in a vector

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-phoenix, boost-spirit-karma

Starting with a trivial problem, I chose to use `boost::spirit::karma` to turn it into something a little trickier.  We have a map that maps entries of an `enum class` to `vector`s of `int`s, I'd like to produce output of the form

> Foo has 3 entries:
>
> Foo has 1
>
> Foo has 5
>
> Foo has 7
>
> ...

if there is an entry `{Foo, {1, 5, 7}}` in the data.

The data format isn't really that important, but if the key of the map were `string`s or `int`s, one could use `karma::lit` to output the saved attribute again.  However, this isn't possible, and the rule consumes an attribute, making it impossible to use it again.

I managed to extract the size of the vector with quite a hack, but I cannot get the name `Foo` to be repeated.

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

#define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3

#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_stl.hpp>

#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma_symbols.hpp>

#include <boost/phoenix/bind/bind_member_variable.hpp>

#include <boost/fusion/include/define_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/std_pair.hpp>

enum class TableName {
    Foo,
    Bar
};

using Map = std::map<TableName, std::vector<int>>;

template<typename OutputIterator>
struct TestGrammar : boost::spirit::karma::grammar<OutputIterator, Map()>
{
    TestGrammar() : TestGrammar::base_type(testRule)
    {
        using boost::spirit::karma::duplicate;
        using boost::spirit::karma::int_;
        using boost::spirit::karma::lit;
        using boost::spirit::karma::_a;
        using boost::spirit::karma::_1;
        using boost::spirit::karma::_val;
        using boost::spirit::karma::skip;
        using boost::phoenix::ref;
        using boost::phoenix::size;

        tableNameSymbols.add
            (TableName::Foo, "Foo")
            (TableName::Bar, "Bar")
        ;

        tableNameRule %= tableNameSymbols;


        // Using _a instead of size_ or sym_ does not work... why?
        pairRule %= tableNameRule[ref(sym_) = _1] <<
            duplicate[
                skip[*int_][ref(size_) = size(_1)] <<
                    lit(" has ") << lit(ref(size_)) << " entries:\n" <<
                    *(lit('\t') << /* tableNameRule[_1 = ref(sym_)] */ lit("IT") << lit(" has ") << int_ << lit('\n'))
                ];

        testRule = *(pairRule << lit('\n'));
    }

    boost::spirit::karma::symbols<TableName, const char *> tableNameSymbols;
    boost::spirit::karma::rule<OutputIterator, TableName()> tableNameRule;
    boost::spirit::karma::rule<OutputIterator, std::pair<TableName, std::vector<int>>()> pairRule;
    boost::spirit::karma::rule<OutputIterator, Map()> testRule;
    private:
    std::size_t size_;
    TableName sym_;
};

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::spirit::karma;

    Map map = {
        {TableName::Foo, {1, 5, 7}},
        {TableName::Bar, {2}}
    };

    std::string output;
    std::back_insert_iterator<std::string> sink(output);

    /*
     * The following outputs

        Foo has 3 entries:
            IT has 1
            IT has 5
            IT has 7

        Bar has 1 entries:
            IT has 2

        It should output:

        Foo has 3 entries:
            Foo has 1
            Foo has 5
            Foo has 7

        Bar has 1 entries:
            Bar has 2
    */

    bool r = generate(
            sink,
            TestGrammar<std::decay<decltype(sink)>::type>(),
            map
        );

    std::cout << output;

    return r == false;
}
```

Comment: You can't use `_a` unless you add a `locals<Whatever>` template parameter to your rule type. I doubt that [this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/n9VcumLzblAoBpIC) is the best way to do what you want (and it is undoubtedly awful), but it seems to work.

Comment: yeah. I don't see a "better" way. Except, not using karma or going full custom directive

Comment: @cv_and_he Thanks for the---given the circumstances---elegant solution!  I guess it is the best way if it's the only way.  This really makes me doubt the usefulness of karma.

Comment: @Xoph I can't say it's "the only way", because I have very little experience with Karma besides trying to answer questions on stackoverflow. [Here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/PSMQ89uAjBcFcV5P) is a possibly (marginally) better version.